# Vyacheslav Captcha validation on Ajax post not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, captcha, ajaxform

I have this following code in Razor view

```
 @{
                var captcha = Html.Captcha("", "Enter the text you see above:", 5, "", false);
            }
            <div style="float:left;">
                @captcha
                @Html.ValidationMessage(captcha.BuildInfo.InputElementId)
            </div>
```

And in the Controller following code is there :

```
var isValidCaptcha = this.IsCaptchaValid("Captcha is not valid");
                if (!isValidCaptcha)
                {
                    validationErrorslist.Add("Captcha is not valid");
                    return new JsonResult { Data = new { IsSuccess = false, Message = validationErrorslist } };
                }
```

Only first time validation is working, but for the second time it is referring to the old value only..
Example : If I gave wrong captcha it is showing as invalid captcha, next time if I correct and submit the page I am still getting invlid catpcha message.

What I am missing here...thanks in advance..

Comment: It looks like the developer of the component is pretty active in helping users figure out the usage.  Have you tried contacting him?  http://vvson.net/Projects/en-US/Project/captchamvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link from codeplex solved my problem http://captchamvc.codeplex.com/discussions/430792

Comment: It helped me too! Thanks for posting it!